# After "." the value entered must replace "00" with two digits only in the textbox

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

May be My Question is not seems like a good one but here is the Description:
I am creating an application in this in a form i have a textbox which is taking input from user here is my Code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0.##}", "0.00");
}
```

this will show value in textbox at pageload:**0.00**
Now after this if i click on backspace button of keyboard then

```
if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == ".")
{
    e.Handled = true;
    int b = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("00");
    textBox1.SelectionStart = b;
}
else
{
    string abc = "0";
    string a = textBox1.Text.TrimStart(abc.ToCharArray());
    textBox1.Text = a;
}
```

this code will lead me to here the textbox has now: **.00** only
but after this when i enter some value then it will take values as;
2334.3423424
but i want to do like
2334.34
it means value should replace **.00** only and user cant enter value after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code will restrict your user in entering only 2 digits after the decimal in your textbox.

```
    //In key press event:
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        TextBox tt = (TextBox)sender;
        if (tt.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1 && tt.Text.Substring(tt.Text.IndexOf('.')).Length >= 3)
         {
           e.Handled = true;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say you want to round up a number up to two decimal places use [`Math.Round(Double, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.100%29.aspxour) function.

In your case you could call

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
double finalValue = Math.Round(value, 2);
textBox1.Text = finalValue.ToString();
```

Also make sure you validate the user input and make sure the user only enters numeric values.

Comment: actually this is not i want to do... sorry